# ServiceStack Swagger Optional Fields in Request DTO

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I have just gotten Swagger up and running and so far its really impressive. I am trying to get some initial endpoints working for a client and I am getting hung up on the [ApiMember] attribute.

So consider this as my request dto (not real just an example):

```
[Route("/person", "POST")
public class Person
{
    public ing Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This will display in Swagger as a parameter type of body.

But I want to convey optional properties... Say for example the Name property is optional. So my assumption would be something like this:

```
[ApiMember(IsRequired = true)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

But what this does is creates the parameter as a path parameter. The example swagger api documentation displays this functionality - where a field in an object is optional. Is there a way to do this with ServiceStack and Swagger?

**EDIT**: I'm already aware that with value types I can set them to nullable and this will set them to optional. I'm also aware that you do not need to set reference types to nullable - but I need to somehow reflect that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack Swagger integration currently [always marks reference type properties in the request as required](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs#L306) (though that could possibly be changed). You may be able to use a `ModelFilter` callback (specified as a property of `SwaggerFeature` when you register that as a plugin) to modify the `Required` property of each `ModelProperty` object sent to your callback. And you can also modify the `Description` of each ModelProperty with this technique, if you need additional descriptive text to mark required/optional fields.

Note that if you want to use the ApiMember attribute to annotate request body parameters, you must specify `ParameterType = "body"` and `Name = "(name of property)"` in the attribute. But there's not a lot you can do with this attribute for request body parameters currently; it's most useful for "query" or "path" ParameterTypes.